# Question about use of new { }

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently working my way through the Apress ASP.NET MVC2 book, and I am a little bit confused as to the user of **new { returnUrl }** in the following code:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart(Cart cart, int productID, string returnUrl)
{
    Product product = productsRepository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productID);
    cart.RemoveLine(product);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

Is it something to do with creating a new string, rather than simply passing a reference to the parameter passed in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's creating an anonymous type with a property `returnUrl` which also has the *value* of `returnUrl`. So it's like this:

```
var anon = new { returnUrl = returnUrl };
return RedirectToAction("Index", anon);
```

Using a name from the expression to determine the name of the property in an anonymous type is called a *projection initializer*.

Does that help to explain it to you at all? If not, you may want to revise [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) in general. They were introduced in C# 3, mostly for LINQ.

Comment: Revisit? Review? I don't know about the OP "revising" anonymous types... ;)

Comment: Great, thanks! One final thing, what is the benefit of passing the returnUrl into RedirectToAction as an anonymous type, rather than just passing it in directly i.e. `RedirectToAction("Index", returnUrl)`

Comment: @MichaelS: That's an MVC issue - I don't do MVC :) Presumably it allows some other bit of code (the view, probably) to access `returnUrl` by name, instead of making the URL the whole model.

Comment: Congrats on the 1K silver badges :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an anonymous type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is an anonymous object. The property in the case above would create a new object with the string property 'returnUrl'.

In this context, it is specifying a url for the ActionResult to redirect the browser to.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax creates an anonymous type. They're created on the fly as needed. In your example it creates a new object with one property and then passes it to the action as a parameter.